# web2py list:string widget breaking on openshift

Tags: web2py, openshift

I've been working on an app that uses that uses 'list:string' in a form to create a list of inputs on the user side. The '+ -' links aren't showing up when I deploy the application to my openshift server but they show up when I'm working in the development server, thoughts?

The same version of web2py is running on both the openshift server and the local server. I am running *2.6.0-development+timestamp.2013.06.27.07.20.48*. I tried updating to the latest version of web2py and the '+ -' links stopped showing up altogether

In the form:
Field('signers','list:string')

In the view
{{=form.custom.widget.signers}}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also copy the latest web2py.js file into your application as well (you can find it in /web2py/welcome/static/js/).